# Get data into the input field after Qr code Scanned

Tags: react-native, qr-code, asyncstorage

I'm trying to get id from Qr code to input field every time Qr is scanned. I tried to use `Async-storage` to store data after scanned but it whenever i scan different qr code it shows the same qr code that is scanned for the very first time.[image: Here is the Image] .

Here is the code that i have used to create scanner page.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Button, Dimensions,Image } from "react-native";
import { BarCodeScanner } from "expo-barcode-scanner";
import colors from "../config/colors";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";

function QrScanner({navigation}) {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleBarCodeScanned();
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === "granted");
    })();
  }, []);

  const handleBarCodeScanned = async({ type, data }) => {
    setScanned(true);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('key', data);
    alert(`Bar code with type ${type},and data ${data} has been scanned!`);
     console.log(await AsyncStorage.getItem('key'));
    
  };
  

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "flex-end",
      }}
    >
      <BarCodeScanner
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
        style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, styles.container]}>
        <Text style={styles.description}>Scan your QR code</Text>
        <Text
          onPress={() =>navigation.navigate('TempRecordStack')}
          style={styles.cancel}>
          Back
        </Text>
        
        </BarCodeScanner>
        {scanned && <Button title={'Tap to Scan Again'} onPress={() => setScanned(false)} />}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
export default QrScanner;

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window')
const qrSize = width * 0.7
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  description: {
    fontSize: width * 0.09,
    fontWeight:"bold",
    marginTop: '30%',
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: '70%',
    color: colors.purple,
    
  },
  cancel: {
    backgroundColor:colors.dark,
    fontSize: width * 0.05,
    fontWeight:"bold",
    padding:4,
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: '30%',
    opacity:0.6,
    color: colors.purple,
  },
})
```

Here is the line of code that i have used to get data from `Async-storage` to get scanned id

```
const [studentId, setStudentId] = useState({});

    
//To get Scanned data
      const getUserId = async () => {
        var code = await AsyncStorage.getItem("key");
        setStudentId(code);
      };
```

Input field

```
<Text style={styles.text1}>UserId : </Text>
        <View style={styles.action}>
          <TextInput style={styles.Input} value={studentId} />

          <FontAwesome
            name="camera"
            size={20}
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.navigate("QrScanner");
            }}
          />
        </View>
```

Comment: Are these two in different screens ? when are you calling the getUserId ?

Comment: Yes they are in different screen. One screen for scanner and another screen is form screen. I have called scanner screen when `camera` icon is pressed.

Comment: Why not pass a param using navigation.navigate('TempRecordStack')? thats the screen with the textinput right ?

Comment: I think we can do that but how do i do that ? and the id should change every new Qr is scanned.

Comment: ok from what i see you press the camera icon in the form and move to scanner and then scan and get back to form, so you can pass the param there and sort it without using async storage, did i understand it correctly ?

Comment: yes you got correctly. I will explain flow for you to make more clear. When user press icon it will call scanner screen and when qr is scanned it will alert the qr code is scanned and they user press back to get into TemStactform to complete form and submit that form.

Comment: can you try my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to use AsyncStorage here which is adding unwanted complexity, you can do this using the parameters like below

```
  const handleBarCodeScanned = async({ type, data }) => {
    setScanned(true);
    alert(`Bar code with type ${type},and data ${data} has been scanned!`);
     navigation.navigate('TempRecordStack',{code:data})
  };
```

And in the other screen you can do like below
Have a use effect

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (route.params?.code) {
      setStudentId(route.params?.code);
    }
  }, [route.params?.code]);
```

This will set the code correctly when the user is navigated back.

Comment: it says `Can't find variable: route`

Comment: its a prop just like navigation you have to add TempRecordStack( {navigation,route})

Comment: I did but i'm unable to get that code in input field and i did console to check if  we are getting code while scanning and it dislpay `Object {
  "code": "0129279",
` when qr is scanned but it doesn't shows in input field.

Comment: Does the useeffect run ? if you console route.params?.code do you see the value ?

Comment: Yes, but it throws `undefined` I'm using function component does that matter?

Comment: you pass the code like this right ? navigation.navigate('TempRecordStack',{code:data})?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224297/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-awani).